# How to remove grandchild from JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

My current JTree is set up as follows

- Root
- Child 1

  - Grandchild 1.1
  - Grandchild 1.2
- Child 2

  - Grandchild 2.1
  - Grandchild 2.2

Question is, how can I remove any of the selected Grandchild? When I tried root.removeNodeFromParent(...), it seems like it only works for Child 1 and Child 2 and not the Grandchild.

```
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) workspaceTree.getModel();
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) root.getChildAt(0);
child.remove(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Grandchild 1.1"));
model.reload(root);
```

I'm having this error saying Argument as a child

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DefaultTreeModel.removeNodeFromParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#removeNodeFromParent%28javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode%29)

> public void removeNodeFromParent(MutableTreeNode node)
>
> Message this to remove node from its parent. This will message nodesWereRemoved to create the appropriate event. This is the preferred way to remove a node as it handles the event creation for you.

For example :

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode grandChild = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) child.getChildAt(0);
model.removeNodeFromParent(grandChild);
// no need to reload the root
```

Comment: I did try removeNodeFromParent, it does work for the Child but not the Grandchild

Comment: Post an SSCCE, then. The bug is in your code, and it's impossible to find it without seeing the code.

Comment: Done, that's a section of the codes and child.remove(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Grandchild 1.1")); seems to be causing the error

Comment: You're not calling the method I advised you to call. And moreover, you're removing a new node, which is thus not a child of the parent node, and which happens to have the same text as the grandchild. You must remove the grandchild node itself. The instance of DefaultMutableTreeNode that is in the tree. Just like you're doing with the first-level child.

Comment: Think you should show me an example? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Is there a way where I can get the GrandChild by its given name? Rather than .getChildAt(0);

Comment: You could walk through all the nodes (using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#depthFirstEnumeration%28%29) for example, and return the first node with the given text. But beware that you have no guarantee that two nodes don't have the same text in the tree. Or you could maintain a parallel Map<String, TreeNode> associating each node with its name.

Comment: Hi, I have tried but still am not able to retrieve the name of the TreeNode

Comment: Done, I found another way, Thanks for the help!